# asynchronous file upload using jquery and python

Tags: jquery, python, django

I want to upload multiple files at a time using javascript and python. Whenever I am doing ajax request an error (403 or forbidden) occurs. I don't know what exactly is going wrong?????
please Help me...

here is my index.html..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="/media/" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<script>
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    /* ... */
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .bar').css(
            'width',
            progress + '%'
        );
     }
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

and here is my view...

```
def update_file(request):
    print "view is called"
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method== "POST":
        image = request.POST.get('image')
        request.user.userprofile.resume.delete()
        request.user.userprofile.resume = image
        request.user.userprofile.save()
    return render_to_response('index.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: Do you have logging for Django enabled on your server?  Often you can see more detail about why the 403 is occurring.  Or, if you set DEBUG=True in your settings, you may get more details on the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you missed the CSRF token https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: the exact error that i am getting  is .....              POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/simple_file_upload/update_file/ 403 (FORBIDDEN) jquery-2.1.1.js:9188
x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send jquery-2.1.1.js:9188
x.extend.ajax jquery-2.1.1.js:9188
upload 127.0.0.1:8000/simple_file_upload/profile/:80
onclick 127.0.0.1:8000/simple_file_upload/profile/:110

Comment: It looks like an error with the csrf token, please read the provided documentation